# Is the wifi at Mataveri International Airport (IPC) fast and robust enough to video call for 1 hour?

Tags: airports, wifi, chile, easter-island, ipc

Is the wifi at  [Mataveri International Airport (IPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mataveri_International_Airport) in [Easter Island, Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_Island) fast and robust enough to video call for 1 hour?

https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/easter-island-mataveri-airport-guide.htm#wifi mentions:

> Free WiFi is available at Mataveri Airport. Connect to the ”Entel” network.

but it it doesn't specify the speed nor the robustness.

Comment: In general, free Airport WiFi rarely guarantees the quality of service needed for VoIP calls and video calls. It is only there to allow casual browsing while you wait for a flight.

Answer (score 8):

The bottleneck isn't the WiFi, but the connection between the island and the rest of the world. I develop an Internet-enabled product and we have a client on Easter Island. I'm given to understand that the entire island shares the equivalent of a 3G connection. I don't recall exact figures from our network logs for latency and throughput, but they're pretty bad. So I would expect voice call to be feasible, but video call to have terrible quality.

Answer (score 5):

(as of 2017) 
As far as I can see, there's no cable going to Easter Island, so it is satellite broadband (4G)

https://www.ses.com/case-study/entel ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191221011024/https://www.ses.com/case-study/entel))

It should be robust, but not speedy.

Comment: Thanks for the great information! Just to confirm, is the WiFi at the IPC airport free?